# Return value always 0 unless I use cout

Tags: c++, return, cout

The function should return 156 with a "Z" input but it outputs 0.

If the letter's U-Z, the function finds the largest factor of the letters numeric value other than the value itself and multiplies it by 12.

Tried putting **cout** in the function and it works somehow. Don't know where's the problem. Someone help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int uz(int n);

int main(){           
    string letter, alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    int alphSize=alphabet.size(), l=0, total=0;

    cin>>letter;
    int letterSize=letter.size();

    for(int i=0;i<letterSize;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<alphSize;j++){
            if(toupper(letter[i])==alphabet[j])
            l=j+1;
        }


        if(l>20&&l<=26){
            l=uz(l);}

        total+=l;
    }
    cout<<total<<endl;
    return 0;
}


int uz(int n){
    int size=1;
    int arr[size];
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if(n%i==0){
            size++;
            arr[size]+=i;
        }
    }
    n=12*arr[size-1];
    //cout<<n;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: You are accessing the array out of bounds with `arr[size]+=i;` (valid array indices go from `0` to `size-1`) -> *undefined behavior*

Comment: Also you are never writing to `arr[size-1]` so it is left with an uninitialized value, so reading from it is also undefined behavior